# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in Post Data From An Android App To a Website

Tags: java, android

hi i have developed a app to post data from android to website. now when i run app i got message Unfortunately app has stopped an then ap closed. From Logcat i found that its android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. i search it and studies these stuff to overcome it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

i tried alot to modify the code but got a lot errors. Please remove android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException by modifying it. 
thanks

The actual java code with android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException is.

```
package com.latlongapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sendButton;

EditText msgTextField;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // make message text field object
    msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
    // make send button object
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
}

 public void send(View v)
    {
        // get the message from the message text box
        String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

        // make sure the fields are not empty
        if (msg.length()>0)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
        else
        {
            // display message if text fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is because you trying to do  networking operation i.e. send data on its main thread.Use AsyncTask to send data.

```
class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          // get the message from the message text box
        String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

        // make sure the fields are not empty
        if (msg.length()>0)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
        else
        {
            // display message if text fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     return null;
}
```

in your send() method use this

```
public void send(View v){
     new SendTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.vyes i know it. but i am unable to use Async TAsk. i tried alot to modify the code but got a lot errors. 
can you please modify this code using Async Task

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your HttpPost action to an acyncTask.

```
public void send(View v){
     String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString(); 
     new SendTask.execute(msg);
     msgTextField.setText("");

}

 private class Send extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String>
{
     protected Long doInBackground(String... txtboxTextValue) {

    // get the message from the message text box
    String msg = txtboxTextValue[0];

    // make sure the fields are not empty
    if (msg.length()>0)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");
     try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }

    }

}

}

}
```